# JQuery click function not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to learn JQuery as well as HTML. I am trying to append a table with a new inputted data. I have a submit button that should run the JQUERY function to append the table. I even put an alert box in the function to see if it is at least running. Is there an obvious reason why my function isn't running at all?

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="form-style-2">
    <div class="form-style-2-heading">Provide your information</div>
    <form name="contactPage" id="contactPage">
        <label for="field1"><span>Name <span class="validated">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="field1" id="name" value="" required /></label>
        <label for="field3"><span>Address <span class="validated">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="field3" id="address" value="" required /></label>
        <label for="field2"><span>Email <span class="validated">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="field2" id="email" value="" required /></label>


        <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="addrow" type="submit" value="Submit" /></label>
    </form>


    <table width="80%">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>testtesttest</p>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mainElement = document.getElementById('contactPage');

    $(mainElement).find('form input[type="submit"]').click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        if ($(evt.target).parents('form')[0].checkValidity()) {
            alert("its working!!");

            var mainElement = document.getElementById('contactPage');

            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("email").val();
            var address = $("address").val();

            var html = '<tr><td>' + name + '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + address + '</td>' +
                             '<td>' + email + '</td></tr>';

            $(mainElement).find('table tbody').append(html);
            $(mainElement).find('form :input[name]').val('')

        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your find line should just be `$(mainElement).find('input[type="submit"]').click(` ... Right now you're trying to find a form inside `#contactPage` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want like this:-

Changes done:-

1.`$(mainElement).find('input[type="submit"]').click(function (evt) {`

2.`$('table tbody').append(html);
$(mainElement).find('input[type="text"]').val('');`

3.Instead of `<p>testtesttest</p>` add `<tbody></tbody>`

***Working example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mainElement = document.getElementById('contactPage');

  $(mainElement).find('input[type="submit"]').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if ($(evt.target).parents('form')[0].checkValidity()) {

      var mainElement = document.getElementById('contactPage');

      var name = $("#name").val();
      var email = $("#email").val();
      var address = $("#address").val();

      var html = '<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + address + '</td><td>' + email + '</td></tr>';
      $('table tbody').append(html);
      $(mainElement).find('input[type="text"]').val('');

    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"> </script>
<body>
<div class="form-style-2">
    <div class="form-style-2-heading">Provide your information</div>
    <form name="contactPage" id="contactPage">
        <label for="field1"><span>Name <span class="validated">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="field1" id="name" value="" required /></label>
        <label for="field3"><span>Address <span class="validated">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="field3" id="address" value="" required /></label>
        <label for="field2"><span>Email <span class="validated">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="field2" id="email" value="" required /></label>

        <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="addrow" type="submit" value="Submit" /></label>
    </form>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</div>
```

Comment: @Konovoloff  glad to help you:):)

Comment: Never concatenate arbitrary data into HTML!  Set the test of those cell elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @techfoobar in his comment you should remove the "form" from your selector as you are already "inside" the form when using your find.

```
<form name="contactPage" id="contactPage">

var mainElement = document.getElementById('contactPage');
$(mainElement).find('input[type="submit"]')
```

when you assign the main element you are assigning the form container, so your selector can not find any submit inside a form, since you are already "inside" your form